# Saving to window.localStorage using a variable?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**What I'm trying to do**

Save data to localStorage using a dynamic variable name.

**How I'm trying to do it**

```
let myVar = 'layout' + companyID //companyID is a number
window.localStorage.setItem(myVar, myData)
```

**What happens**

If I just set localStorage directly using a string, it works, i.e.,

```
window.localStorage.setItem('company34523', myData)
```

However, localStorage fails to properly retrieve data if I pass in the string as a variable like `myVar`.

I'm not sure why this is occurring - presumably there would be no difference between

```
setItem('company234', myData)
```

and

```
let myString = 'company234'
setItem(myString, myData)
```

Comment: Um, should make no difference.

Comment: Sounds more like variable value isn't what you expect it to be. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Have you tried with template literal?

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake - the variable string was not being set properly. epascarello is right.